# Flutter Cubit state gets emitted twice

Tags: flutter, state, cubit

In Flutter, when I call the cubit method below, the state is getting emitted twice.

Can someone help me find what's wrong with my code?

Cubit class:

```
class AlertCubit extends Cubit<AlertState> {
  AlertCubit() : super(AlertInitial());

  void alert(InfoAlertData alertInfo) {
    emit(AlertInitial());
    **emit(NewAlert(alertInfo));**
  }
}
```

Where I call this function from another cubit:

```
class CustomersCubit extends Cubit<CustomersState> {
  CustomersCubit(
      {required this.alertCubit,
    })
      : super(CustomersInitial());

  final AlertCubit alertCubit;

///removed irrelevant code

void markMissing(int loanId) async {
    if (collectionCubit.active) {
    } else {
      **alertCubit.alert(InfoAlerts.startCollect);**
    }
  }

///removed irrelevant code
}
```

I passed cubit as a parameter in main:

```
///removed irrelevant code

return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => AlertCubit(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (BuildContext cusContext) => CustomersCubit(
            **alertCubit: BlocProvider.of<AlertCubit>(cusContext),**
          ),
        ),
///removed irrelevant code
```

I am new to flutter and bloc; any help is appreciated